# What is the format of ga:region?

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization

How to convert ISO 3166 GeoChart response into ga:region Google Analytics format?

For example:

- GB-ENG -> England
- GB-SCT -> Scotland

Comment: Interesting question, can you maybe give some more examples? Following the question :)

Comment: **GB-NIR** for **Northern Ireland**... Short format is the only one field of the GeoChart's _regionClick_ event, GA expects full format. And that's the problem.

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're trying to do -- you can for instance pass values in to the chart using this format: `{v:'GB-ENG', f:'England'}` which will allow you to have the formatted value equivalent to what you want to pass to analytics, but depending on how you are passing the value, you may not have access to that information.